# Airflow Module not found when airflow container is started with host user

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I am using docker-compose (version 2) to bring up airflow containers. Inside docker-compose, i am changing the user to be the host user where i am running the docker container. See example below:

```
webserver:
    image: image_name
    user: ${USER_ID}:${GROUP_ID}
```

When i bring up the container, it comes up with the host user but complains about the airflow module.

hostuser@container:/opt/airflow$ airflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in 
from airflow.**main** import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow'

Please advise.